# PHP Response without HTML

Tags: php, android, response

I'm trying to get the response from database for further usage.eg: userID

However, instead of just getting the userID as the answer,
I'm getting the response from php server with HTML
It shows every HTML tag that I had in my php file,including the comments

**EDIT**
The php file just simply look like this

```
<?php
 include "Header.php";
 include "main.php"; 

 $path = $_SESSION['username'].$_POST['Case_no'];
 mkdir($path);
 echo $path;
?>
```

Everything working fine,but the output look something like (let say the $path is "1234")

`1234 口 <!--HTML comments and scripts from the webhost-->`

If there is any other HTML code in the php,say a link at the front
The result shows
`<a href="xxx.html">Link</a> 1234 口 <!--HTML comments and scripts-->`

Anyway to get rid of this?
The required answer is just merely 1234

**ADD ON**
I have tried the following example in http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/ (where you can see the whole code)
Instead of getting the "Chirp chirp" as response, 
I'm getting sth like "Chirp Chirp 口 " –

Comment: PHP outputs whatever you tell it to output. Don't tell it to output HTML if you don't want that.

Comment: I just put "echo $variable" in the php file

Comment: You say yourself that "It shows every HTML tag that I had in my php file,including the comments" - so you don't have just `echo $var` in there.

Comment: Sorry if my eng confused you.I have put in the real code. However,even without the HTML tag in php(no php for all the included files too), the outcome still having a HTML tag at the behind(webhost).

In another words, all the php response includes HTML. My question is how to get the response WITHOUT having HTML

Comment: We don't know what is in the includes, or how you're calling that page. Remove the includes and see what happens.

Comment: remove the include, then my apps will not be functioning.I don;t think that is the point. If you wanna will the whole code, I can direct you to this example:http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2010/09/android-development-implementing-a-simple-client-server-model/

Instead of getting the "Chirp chirp" as response, I'm getting sth like "Chirp Chirp 口 <!--webhost analytic code blah blah blah-->"

Comment: The problem is solved by using my PC as the server. The HTML tag and comments is actually generate by the free webhosting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

send "text/plain" header to tell the client that this text shoudn't be interpreted as HTML, because default content type is HTML

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

Comment: do you mean I have to add this to the php file? or my android coding?

Comment: I mean to the PHP code, if this doesn't help check your other files, I'm sure there are some HTML tags

Comment: so can I say that it is the problem of the server setting?
because it doesn't really comes from my coding.
can I clear my doubt that :response will actually return everything including all HTML tag in the php file?

Comment: the reason could be some HTML tags that exist in one of your PHP files. the server itself usually doesn't append or prepend additional text or tags, so check your php files

Comment: Yes, it does usually add headers.

Comment: thanks for approving my answer, can you please upvote it, it's a little bit strange to see accepted answer with negative votes :D

Answer (score 0):

Like Mat said, PHP outputs whatever you tell it to output. Don't tell it to output HTML if you don't want that.

if you don't want to output some HTML, persumably written in Header.php and main.php - DO NOT include these files

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using my PC as the server by using the same coding I have shown. The HTML tag and comments is actually generate by the free webhosting side